# How to show a line for every line_item.quantity (Liquid)

Tags: html, shopify, liquid, liquid-layout

In a page.template, I'm trying to display a separate line for every product I have in the cart, meaning that if the same product is present, in example, 3 times, I need to show it in 3 separate lines.

The basic structure is this:

```
    {% for item in cart.items %}
               {% for quantity in item.quantity %}
                 <p>show something</p>
               {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

But that `<p>`is not showing.

Comment: it seems that Liquid's 'for' just works if you have an array as the 'in' argument, so since item.quantity is not an array but an integer value, the for is not working. still looking for a solution

Answer (score 0):

This sintax is working:

```
{% for item in cart.items %}
           {% for i in (1..item.quantity) %}
            <p>show something</p>
           {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

(snap...! auto high-five)